# Angular css class binding

Tags: css, angular5

Can anyone suggest me how to integrate this I have 8 css class and I want it to interpolate them in the first div
, these are the class name featured_destination1 to featured_destination8

```
<div *ngFor="let destination of destinations;" class="box featured_destination1">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="featured_img" src="https://d2aixmiphfue7s.cloudfront.net/fimages/{{destination.FeatureImage}}">
    </div>
    <div class="gradient">
      <div class="boxcontent">
        <div class="featuredtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur nec risus adipiscing elit</div>
        <div class="featuredlocation">{{destination.TextLine1}} </div>
        <div class="featuredcountry">{{destination.LocationName}}Y</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So for every iteration you would like to have a new class with the number of the looped index (first loop class = featured_destination1, second loop class= featured_destination2 and so on)?

Comment: yes @MrBuggy that what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the index in a variable for every loop, so you get the current looped index. After this you can concat the value to the class name.

Try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let destination of destinations; let i = index;" class="box featured_destination{{i}}">
```

The index starts with 0 for the first loop. So if you want the class name starts with 1 in case of 0 try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let destination of destinations; let i = index;" class="box featured_destination{{i + 1}}">
```

or

```
<div *ngFor="let destination of destinations; let i = index + 1;" class="box featured_destination{{i}}">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MrBuggy you save me thank you,thank you

Comment: @JAIMEGAFFODJR No problem, you'r welcome. Please mark the answer as correct. :-) Cheers

Comment: MrBuggy I have another question how can I message you privately?

Comment: @JAIMEGAFFODJR Sure, here's a link to a private chat room: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1183/angular-2-css-class-binding?tab=general